# Scala run test by skipping compilation

Tags: scala, sbt

We have a giant monolith and I simply want to run a test that only deals with a handful of classes (or files). i.e. the dependency graph if seen from the test file is pretty small

Is it possible to set the compilation mode to on demand or compile just what's needed?

We use sbt

Comment: Is this local, or on a build server?  If local, `sbt` should already be compiling only what changed.  Since the dependency graph can't generally be determined without everything being compiled, you can't escape bringing everything up to date.

Comment: this is local and it's my first time on this project haha. I guess I'll have to compile everything once I guess!

I remember some build tools allowing you to download already compiled classes from a build server to local. Does sbt support that?

Comment: Yes, kinda. 
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Remote-Caching.html